# Solving unsteady flow in a syringe

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, bernoulli-equation

I want to solve the problem of unsteady flow in a syringe. The piston as shown in the below figure is pushed by some force $F$, resulting in flow velocity $u_0$ from the orifice. The flow velocity varies with time and hence is an unsteady problem. I want to relate between $F$ and $u_0$.

[image: piston pusehd flow]

I don't know how to solve. Please provide me some help.

Comment: Have you solved it for steady flow yet?

Comment: *The flow velocity varies with time and hence is an unsteady problem.* Because you vary $F$ with time?

Comment: @Gert Since the orifice has some length, so I believe the flow velocity will take some time to come down to the steady-state value. I may be wrong.

Comment: @Sayanb6292 No, you are right but you didn't make it very clear that that is what you're after: the transient regime at the 'mouth' of the syringe.

Comment: @Gert Yes. That transient velocity is needed to understand how it varies with F.

Comment: @Sayanb6292: you should at least read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hagen%E2%80%93Poiseuille_equation#Startup_of_Poiseuille_flow_in_a_pipe. Might be above your paygrade though! ;-)

Comment: The order of magnitude of the time required for the capillary flow (which dominates the force F) to come to steady state is on the order of $D^2/\nu$, where D is the capillary diameter and $\nu$ is the kinematic viscosity of the fluid.  What value do you calculate?